# Drilling down date span with ColdFusion or SQL

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a voucher system in my shopping cart, the vouchers have a valid from date and a valid to date. **What is the best way to ensure they are valid?**

I was stupidly setting today's date, and then asking the database if today's date is greater than or equal to the start date. i.e is 02/02/2012 `GTE` 15/02/2012 it's obviously not! I was then asking the database if the expiry date is `LTE` to today's date. i.e is 29/02/2012 `LTE` 15/02/2012 again it's not! Sounded right when I put it down paper!

Here is the code below, i am using a custom tag to convert the date correctly as this helps greatly with European dates! FYI: The date fields are set to date in the sql database.

What I need to do is make sure that today's date falls between the start date and end date. Would it be best to create a date span with ColdFusion or use the `BETWEEN` operator in ColdFusion??

```
<cfset todaysDate = DateFormat(now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")>
<CF_convertDate inputVariable="todaysDate" inputMask="EU" outputType="odbcdate" outputVariable="myDate">

<cfquery name="chk_voucher" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT 
  uid_vouchers,
  txt_vouch_name,
  txt_vouch_descrip,
  txt_vouch_code,
  txt_vouch_type,
  txt_vouch_percent,
  txt_vouch_value,
  dte_vouch_expiry,
  dte_vouch_start,
  uid_vouch_webid,
  bit_vouch_archived,
  txt_vouch_asign
FROM dbo.tbl_vouchers
WHERE bit_vouch_archive=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="no">
AND dte_vouch_start >= #myDate# AND dte_vouch_expiry <= #myDate#
AND txt_vouch_code=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.txt_vouch_code#">
</cfquery>
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea, you just have your operators reversed.

- The start date has to be *before* the active date, AND
- The end date has to be *after* the active date

Just change this in your WHERE clause:

```
AND dte_vouch_start <= #myDate# AND dte_vouch_expiry >= #myDate#
```

(Of course, your `#myDate#` variables should be in `cfqueryparam` tags.)

Comment: Thanks guys! Obviously not thinking clearly! I will add the `<cfquerypram` tags now! Was just testing without. Both answers were correct! Selected this one as correct and voted up "Andriy M's" answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
AND dte_vouch_start <= #myDate# AND dte_vouch_expiry >= #myDate#
```

or

```
AND #myDate# BETWEEN dte_vouch_start AND dte_vouch_expiry
```